# How to find the identifier of the navigationController from a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uistoryboard

I have a  2 navigation controllers in a Tab Bar Controller which point to same View. This gives me 2 different instances of that view in 2 different tabs. Now I want the view to behave differently based on its parent Navigation Controller.

```
if id == "parent1"{
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

[image]

So how can I get the identifier of the `navigationController` in `ViewController` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `restorationIdentifier` which you can set in the storyboard; It's right underneath the storyboard identifier field in the identity inspector.

Get the current navigation controller from the view controller's property

```
let id = self.navigationController.restorationIdentifier
```

Note that by setting this property, you are telling the system the view controller should be saved for restoration, which might have unexpected consequences. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621499-restorationidentifier).

Alternatively, you might want to consider using subclasses or some kind of property on your view controller class (e.g. maybe using [IBInspectable](https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) etc).

Comment: Why not use Storyboard Identifier?

Comment: There is no public property on `UIViewController` that returns the storyboard identifier. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).